# Extract .swu file using c#

Tags: c#, docker

How can I extract ".swu" file using c#. I had tried below code but I am getting `Enf od central directory not found error`.

```
        var retrunFileName = wiceBridgePath + "EncryptedSWU.swu";
        var decryptedSWUFolder = wiceBridgePath + "DecyptedFiles";

        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(retrunFileName, decryptedSWUFolder);
```